# Is there any way to verify that $1/i = -i$ without using relation $i^2 = -1$?

Tags: complex-numbers

Is there any way to show it without using calculations involving expressions $i^2 = -1$ or $\pm i = {\sqrt {-1}}$?

Comment: What is your definition of $i$ if it is not $i^2=-1$?  All proofs are based on the definition.

Comment: This like asking if we can prove a result about $i$ without knowing what $i$ is. The short answer is NO.

Comment: Can you prove that $i/i$ = 1 without knowing that $i^2 = -1$?

Comment: You could use the relationship $i = -\frac 1i$ or the relationship $i^3 =-i$....This is vague in that if you dont use $i^2 =-1$ what *do* you use.  You could use $\frac 1z = \frac {\overline z}{|z|^2}$ and $\overline{i} = -i$ and $|i| = 1$.... but that's just spinning wheels.

Comment: "Can you prove that i/i = 1 without knowing that i2=−1"   Of course.  For all $x \ne 0$ by definition $\frac xx = x*\frac 1x=1$ because $\frac 1x$ is defined to be the multiplicative inverse of $x$ i.e.  the number $w$ so that $x*w = 1$.

Comment: To say $\frac 1m = $ whatever we have to no something about $m$.  After all, $\frac 13 \ne -3$.  What's the difference between $3$ and $i$?

Comment: So, is it impossible to calculate exact value of $\frac{1}{i}$ without axiom $i^2 = -1$?

Comment: Just came to mind: $$\frac{1}{i}=\frac{1}{\cos(\frac{\pi}{2})+i\sin(\frac{\pi}{2})}=\frac{1}{e^{\frac{i\pi}{2}}}=\frac{1}{e^{\frac{i\pi}{2}}}\times \frac{e^{-\frac{i\pi}{2}}}{e^{-\frac{i\pi}{2}}}=e^{-\frac{i\pi}{2}}=\cos(-\frac{\pi}{2})+i\sin(-\frac{\pi}{2})=-i$$ :D

Comment: In that case relation of $i$ to $-1$ is hidden in $e^{ix}$.

Answer (score 2):

You need some definition of $i$ to prove anything about it.  Without the definition, it is an undefined character.  The usual definition is that $i^2=-1$.  If you do not want to use that, you need to provide an alternative.  If your definition is consistent with usual practice, $i^2=-1$ becomes a theorem that is proved from your definition.  Your question would then make sense, asking if we can get from your definition to $\frac 1{i}=-1$ without passing through $i^2=-1$.  What is your definition of $i$?

Comment: $i$ is just a number that does not lie on the axis of real numbers with some "obvious" relations to real numbers and itself, like $3i=i+i+i$, $i-i=0$, $\frac{i}{i}=1$ and so on.

Comment: Your definition is clearly inadequate without saying what relations you consider obvious.  It sounds like you are trying to define $i$ in such a way you can make a two dimensional vector space, but the vector space axioms do not require or define the multiplication of two vectors.  Without that there will be no way to define $i^2$, let alone prove it is $-1$

Answer (score 0):

We can.

We know that $i = (0,1)$ and $1/i$ is the multiplicative inverse of $i$. We are trying to find, say $1/i= (a,b)$, such that $(0,1)\times(a,b) = (1,0)$, i.e. $$(-b, a)  = (1,0)$$ and got $b = -1, a = 0$. The other side of invers can be check similarly. Thus $1/i = (a, b)  = (0,-1) = -(0,1) = -i$.

Comment: This is using complex multiplication, which is defined by using $i^2=-1$.